# Saving custom taxonomies to post as checkbox on frontend

Tags: custom-taxonomy, front-end

I am trying to save custom taxonomies by choosing checkboxes. Normally if it is selectbox, there is no problem. But when I use checkboxes to choose terms it doesn't save. I am suspected that it is an array problem but I could not solve. I request your very kind help. Sorry my bad English. Thank you.

Here is the part to add the post;
`

```
// ADD THE FORM INPUT TO $new_post ARRAY
$new_post = array(
'post_title'        =>  $title,
'post_category'     =>  array($_POST['cat']),  // Usable for custom taxonomies too  
'post_status'       =>  'publish',           // Choose: publish, preview, future, draft, etc.
'post_type'         =>  'post',  //'post',page' or use a custom post type if you want to
'tax_input'         =>  array( 'genre' => array($_POST['genre']) )  // support for custom taxonomies.   
);
```

`

And This is saving the post,

`//SAVE THE POST
    $pid = wp_insert_post($new_post, $wperror);
    wp_set_post_terms($pid,array($_POST['genre']),'genre',true);`

The code below is for my custom taxonomy, genre will be something like music type.
`

```
<?php
$genres = get_terms('genre', 'orderby=id&hide_empty=0');
$counter = 0;
foreach ($genres as $genre) {
$counter++;
$option = '<input type="checkbox" name="genre[]" id="'.$genre->name.'" value="'.$genre->name.'">';
$option .= '<label for="genre">'.$genre->name.'</label>';
echo $option;
}
?>
```

`

Comment: Try printing the $_POST array to see if you're getting the taxos as genre array.

Comment: Thank you for yur answer, I already tried that one but it doesnt work. If same foreach loop is select box it works, but when it comes to checkbox problem starts,

Comment: What do you exactly get with the print_r? Try working with debug = true.

Comment: **When I send, print_r,** `print_r(array($_POST['genre']));` **I got this;** `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Term1 [1] => Term2 [2] => Term3 ) )`

Comment: My Wp debug function is also open but I do not get any error. My opinion: array works, but the problem is with checkbox. Colud yu please check foreach loop at the 3rd code.

Comment: Try this in your save function, wp_set_post_terms($pid,$_POST['genre'],'genre',true); and also change your tax input to array( 'genre' => $_POST['genre']).

Comment: Any luck yet? The $_POST['genre'] is already an array, and you're explicitly making it an array by array($_POST['genre']), hence your values aren't getting saved! So I asked you to change it, just remove the array(...) around $_POST['genre'] and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Change the value of each checkbox to term slug instead of name, and change

```
wp_set_post_terms($pid,array($_POST['genre']),'gen re',true);
```

To

```
 wp_set_post_terms($pid,(array)$_POST['genre'],'gen re',true);
```

Comment: Thanks [toda :) ] @bainternet. Say, can you add an example with a save button so i could configure it to be saved from the frontend? looking to mark categories / taxmonies in checkboxes then saving them from the front end... (a little example would be very helpfull if possible)

Comment: Know what.. its a weird comment, thanks for the code example - going to create a question with my recent code and hope for the best... :) - thanks again..

Comment: Glad I could help, Alo davar :)